# Gamma function with complex input in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, math, complex-numbers, gamma-function

I am trying to compute the gamma function in Tensorflow. The argument in the function is a sum of a float that comes from the tensor and an imaginary part. Normally, I could just exponentiate the `tf.math.lgamma` function, however, it does not accept complex numbers. Is there any workaround that could solve this issue?

Comment: The comment "Add test when the lgamma kernel supports complex numbers" in `tf`'s source code suggest that complex values are not implemented, but might be in future versions. The `lgamma` of `scipy.special` allows for complex values, though. Not sure if this might help.

Comment: Thanks! I tried `scipy.special.gamma` but it cannot be done for tensors, sadly. I solved my problem - I wrote a function that uses Lanczos Approximation for tensors. Works well!

Comment: Hi, good to hear. I somewhat expected that Scipy will not work directly, but that you'll need a wrapper. Rewriting the `lgamma` approximation seems quite a work (unnecessary?). Anyhow, as it works, it's Okey ...Cheers.